# watir unable to locate element with type = "File"

Tags: ruby, watir, watir-webdriver

the html on the page contains:

```
<input type="File" name="File" size="70" value="" class="inputfield_en">
```

I'm trying to set the value using ruby (1.9.2) and watir-webdriver (0.3.5)

```
@browser.file_field(:type=>"File",:name=>"File",:class=>"inputfield_en").to_subtype.set("#{Dir.pwd}/status_feed_for_test.xml")
```

But I get:

```
   .rvm/gems/ruby-1.9.2-p290/gems/watir-webdriver-0.3.5/lib/watir-webdriver/elements/element.rb:248:in `assert_exists': unable to locate element, using {:type=>"file", :name=>"File", :class=>"inputfield_en", :tag_name=>"input"} (Watir::Exception::UnknownObjectException)
```

Is this because the html contains type File with a capital "F"?  (I have no control of the HTML).  How to fix?

Comment: If the issue is the type being specified in the HTML then it's something we need to fix in either webdriver or watir-webdriver since per the HTML4 standards those type specifications are CI (Case Insensitive) see: http://www.w3.org/TR/html4/interact/forms.html#h-17.4

Comment: As a debugging and/or diagnostic step you could try doing this 'puts @browser.file_fields.size' (should = the number of file input fields on the page) vs `@browser.file_fields(:name => 'File').size`  etc.

Comment: Yeah  not good.   I think this is an issue, see the comments on https://github.com/jarib/watir-webdriver/issues/72 for a possible workaround.  It's technically valid HTML even through 99%+ of the HTML I've seen never uses upper-case when defining 'type' attributes and I've never seen a single example in any book or tutorial (or even the HTML spec) of doing it that way.  Unless they can find a way to address this without a negative impact on performance, I suspect that this might not be fixed as the 'cost' to everyone would be too high relative to the benefit to the few folks the bug affects.

Comment: I'd ask the developers if they can lowercase that stuff to improve testability.  It's a simple fix, and it if saves time on the test side, the value to the business could make it well worth doing.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

In watir, you only need to specify as many selectors as necessary to uniquely identify the element. In this case, you probably only need `:name`.

```
@browser.file_field(:name=>"File")
```

**Update**: It appears that you've encountered a bug in watir-webdriver where `file_field` only selects a field with lowercase `type="file"`. You may want to try a more generic selection method:

```
@browser.element(:xpath => '//input[@type="File"]')
```

Comment: of if the name is not unique, :class might work also.  For that matter if there is only one file input tag on the page then you might not need any selectors (same as :index  =>0)

Comment: I tried the minimum of selectors at first, then 2 then 3.  The post to stackoverflow was after having tried all 3.

Comment: sounds like this issue, https://github.com/jarib/watir-webdriver/issues/72, but no recent activity around it.